# Python plot dates as X, prices as Y

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data:

```
apple[0].head()
Out[76]: 
         Date      Open      High       Low     Close  Adj Close     Volume
0  1999-12-31  3.604911  3.674107  3.553571  3.671875   3.204494   40952800
1  2000-01-03  3.745536  4.017857  3.631696  3.997768   3.488905  133949200
2  2000-01-04  3.866071  3.950893  3.613839  3.660714   3.194754  128094400
3  2000-01-05  3.705357  3.948661  3.678571  3.714286   3.241507  194580400
4  2000-01-06  3.790179  3.821429  3.392857  3.392857   2.960991  191993200
```

and I am trying to plot prices (Close) on the y-axis, and Date on the x-axis.

If I write

```
plt.plot(apple[0]['Close'])
plt.title('AAPL Closing Prices')
plt.show()
```

it works but it plots numbers on the x-axis, while I would like to have the dates on the horizontal axis.

I tried

```
plt.plot(apple[0]['Date'],apple[0]['Close'])
plt.title('AAPL Closing Prices')
plt.show()
```

but it is not working. How can I make it work?

The type of `apple[0]['Date']` is `pandas.core.series.Series` if that helps.

```
apple[0].plot(x = 'Date', y = 'Close')
```

gives me the following picture

[image]

doesn't show dates after 2015-11-24. How can I show more dates on the x-horizontal axis?

Comment: `apple[0].plot(x='Date', y='Close')` or `apple[0].set_index('Date').plot()`?

Comment: Hi it works but I would like to show more dates on the x-axis. How can I do that? Please see my edit above.

Comment: See if [this](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/dates_api.html) helps, e.g, DayLocator.

Comment: @adrCoder, i have updated my code to give you additional example with x-ticks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You able to use just DataFrame methods, like this.

```
In[14]: apple[0]
Out[14]: 
        Date      Open      High       Low     Close  Adj Close     Volume
0 1999-12-31  3.604911  3.674107  3.553571  3.671875   3.204494   40952800
1 2000-01-03  3.745536  4.017857  3.631696  3.997768   3.488905  133949200
2 2000-01-04  3.866071  3.950893  3.613839  3.660714   3.194754  128094400
3 2000-01-05  3.705357  3.948661  3.678571  3.714286   3.241507  194580400
4 2000-01-06  3.790179  3.821429  3.392857  3.392857   2.960991  191993200

apple[0].plot(x = 'Date', y = 'Close')
```

[image]

This version with explicitly matplotlib usage:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import dates
from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

plt.plot(df['Date'], df['Close'])
plt.legend()
ax = plt.gca().get_xaxis()

ax.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(1))
ax.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
ax.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%Y-%b-%d'))

for item in ax.get_ticklabels():
    item.set_rotation(45)
```

[image]

Comment: I get `NameError: name 'MultipleLocator' is not defined`

Comment: right. i just have added this in my code: from matplotlib.ticker import MultipleLocator

Comment: I get an error `RuntimeError: Locator attempting to generate 1112 ticks from 736281.0 to 737392.0: exceeds Locator.MAXTICKS

<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>`  how can I fix that?

Comment: Looks like for your data it's too small steps (MultipleLocator(1) - "1" for major, and MultipleLocator(0.1) - "0.1" for minor). Let's try bigger steps. "20" and "4" for example

Answer (score 1):

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html

You can add custom ticks/ticklabels for the axes, the matplotlib documentation is quite detailed. Have a look.